# How to set scrapy spider to run over multiple pages - without next page button

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I'm struggling my head around to set scrapy run over multiple pages from the start till the end of the produced results. Unfortunately the website do not have a "next page" button which makes the things even harder. Here is the website results https://www.imot.bg/pcgi/imot.cgi?act=3&slink=5fuby1&f1=1.

```
import scrapy
import logging

class ApartmentsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apartments'
    allowed_domains = ["www.imot.bg"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.imot.bg/pcgi/imot.cgi?act=3&slink=5f8c9v&f1=1"
                , "https://www.imot.bg/pcgi/imot.cgi?act=3&slink=5f8c9v&f1=2"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # apartments = response.xpath("//div[@class='price']/text()").get()
        apartments = response.xpath("//a[@class='lnk1']")
        for apartment in apartments:
            apartment_type = apartment.xpath(".//text()").get()
            apartment_link = apartment.xpath(".//@href").get()

            yield response.follow(url = apartment_link, callback=self.parse_apartment, meta={"apartment_type":apartment_type,
                                                                                            "apartment_link" : apartment_link}) 

    def parse_apartment(self, response):
        apartment_type = response.request.meta["apartment_type"]
        apartment_address = response.xpath("//form/div[2]/span[1]/text()").get()
        apartment_price = response.xpath("//td/div[1]/strong[1]/text()").get()
        apartment_sqm = response.xpath("//ul[@class='imotData']/li[2]/text()").get()
        offered_by = response.xpath("//div/b[1]/text()").get()
        contact = response.xpath("//div[8]/span[1]/span[1]/text()").get()
        apartment_link = response.request.meta["apartment_link"]

        yield {
            "apartment_type" : apartment_type,
            "apartment_address" : apartment_address,
            "apartment_price" : apartment_price,
            "apartment_sqm" : apartment_sqm,
            "apartment_link" : apartment_link,
            "offer" : offered_by,
            "contact" : contact
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this. If you continue to click the numbers and go to the next page, you can look at the URL and see how it is. With this website, going to the next change is simply add +1 to the URL. I hope  the code makes more sense. Add these 4 lines to your parse method. I used the number 26 because that is the last page for the listings.

```
  def parse(self, response):
        # apartments = response.xpath("//div[@class='price']/text()").get()
        apartments = response.xpath("//a[@class='lnk1']")
        for apartment in apartments:
            apartment_type = apartment.xpath(".//text()").get()
            apartment_link = apartment.xpath(".//@href").get()

            yield response.follow(url = apartment_link, callback=self.parse_apartment, meta={"apartment_type":apartment_type,
                                                                                            "apartment_link" : apartment_link})

        next_page = self.base_url + str(self.num)
        if self.num <= 26:
            self.num += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: How this could be made a dynamic, 26 is working only for the selection. What would happen if the pages are less or more?